# Spring MVC Controller response as a static content to cache in browser

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tiles

I would like to my response of the Spring MVC Controller be seen as a static content in the browser. Just to fetch once and then get it from browser cache to get `304 Not Modified` status code.
I have ordinary Spring MVC controller with simple method. `simpleService.getVariables()` is getting huge content from the database. It returns String.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/jsContent.htm")
public ModelAndView jsContent(@RequestParam("ver") String version, 
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("jsContent");
    mav.addObject("variables", simpleService.getVariables());
    return mav;
}
```

Response is handling by Apache Tiles. The `firstPart` is ordinary JavaScript file, and the `secondPart` is the `String` added to the `ModelAndView` object.

```
<definition name="javascript" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/javascript.jsp" />
<definition name="jsContent" extends="javascript">
    <put-attribute name="firstPart" expression="/js/content/static.js" />
    <put-attribute name="secondPart" expression="${variables}" />
</definition>
```

To enable `expressions` in tiles I have added this `tilesProperties`:

This is my `tiles/javascript.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="firstPart" />
<tiles:insertAttribute name="secondPart" />
```

I have only achieved `304 Not Modified` status code by added this Spring filter to the `web.xml`. However content is still fetching every time, and by `Etag` header comparison the status code is `304` when there is any change.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>etagFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

How can I get cached response of my Spring Controller? I have tried to achieve this by HTTP Headers but it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

The ETag method will not suit your need here. The way the filter works is that it calls the controller each time a request is received, it then computes the Hash of the response, compares the hash (ETag) with the Etag sent in the request, and if they match, the filter assumes data has not changed, and sends the client 304 with no response body.

As you can see, this method does not reduce the amount of work your actual controller needs to do for a request, it only improves bandwidth utilization and provides faster response to the client (Since instead of sending the response body, we are only sending a status code).

So, for your case, you should use the `Last-Modified` response header and `If-Modified-Since` request header. To do this with Spring MVC, you can try the following method:
1. In your controller, maintain a time stamp in millis, which should be the same as the last modified time for the resource. I set this to the deployment time, with the assumption that my content is not going to be modified while the application is live. You may chose to update this time as you wish, if you want to force browsers to load a fresh copy, even if they have a older version.

1. Accept org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest as a parameter to your controller method.
2. In your method, do the actual processing, only if `webRequest.checkNotModified(lastModifiedTime)` is false.

Sample code:

```
public class MyController {
//Injected 
private long lastModifiedTime;

public void getFullSdk(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletRequest request, 
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    if (webRequest.checkNotModified(lastModifiedTime)) {
        return;
    } else {
        // real expensive code goes here
        // write to response
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps.